# Writing SQL Query for a Specific Time Range

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp

I need to write a query for the amount of visiting attempts to a site in the full two minute span from 11:36 through 11:37 on [05/Sep/2017]. I know the answer is supposed to be 7 based on the data set, but everything I enter keeps giving me an output of zero. I have tried timestamp between those values. I have tried timestamp where min=x and max=y. I'm not sure if my formatting is just incorrect or what, but I have been struggling since 2:30, and I am getting hopeless.
[This is what my query looks like. I have tried a few different operations but this is the most recent attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am96w.png)

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) What is the data type of the column you being used?

Comment: I'm using a timestamp column. My database is SQLite. I tried the query set up that you showed below, but it still gave me an output of 0.

Comment: What is the format of your dates in the table?

Comment: the dates are formatted in the table as [05/Sep/2017 followed by a time so the full timestamp column has values that look like [05/Sep/2017:11:29:31]

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a query that looks like this:

```
select count(*)
from t
where col >= '2017-09-05 11:36:00' and
      col < '2017-09-05 11:38:00'
```

The exact format for the date/time constant would vary by database, but this is a typical format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datepart to build an lower and upper time range.  I show how to keep all the comparison in bigint

```
declare @StartDate as datetime='2020-10-19 11:36:00'
declare @EndDate as datetime='2020-10-19 11:37:00'

SELECT [created_at]
 ,cast(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(19),[created_at], 
 121),':',''),'-',''),' ','') as bigint) int_date,

 cast(DATEPART(year, @StartDate) * 10000 + DATEPART(month, @StartDate) * 100 + 
DATEPART(day, @StartDate) as varchar)+format(datepart(Hour,@StartDate),'0#')+format(datepart(Minute,@StartDate),'0#')
+format(datepart(Second,@StartDate),'0#')
int_date_compare

FROM mytable
 where cast(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(19),[created_at], 121),':',''),'-',''),' ','') as bigint) 
  >=
 cast(DATEPART(year, @StartDate) * 10000 + DATEPART(month, @StartDate) * 100 + 
DATEPART(day, @StartDate) as varchar)+format(datepart(Hour,@StartDate),'0#')+format(datepart(Minute,@StartDate),'0#')
 +format(datepart(Second,@StartDate),'0#')
 <=
 cast(DATEPART(year, @EndDate) * 10000 + DATEPART(month, @EndDate) * 100 + 
 DATEPART(day, @StartDate) as varchar)+format(datepart(Hour,@EndDate),'0#')+format(datepart(Minute,@EndDate),'0#')
+format(datepart(Second,@EndDate),'0#')
order by created_at
```